# Nav-Bar is out of line

Tags: html, css, html-lists, nav

I'm writing a website for my Minecraft server.

There's a navigation bar at the top. In the top right, I want my logo (an image) and then the page title
But I tried that and it's out of line. image:

[image]

Here's the code:

```css
h1 {
    
  font-size: 70px;  
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #d82d83;
 
  
}

nav {
    background: ;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
}
nav ul {
    float: right;
    
    list-style-type: none;

}
nav li {
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    display: inline-flex;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background-color: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 15px;
    
}
nav ul li a{
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
}
nav ul li img {
    display: grid;
    place-items: left;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <h1><a href="#"><img src="C:\Users\John\Desktop\website\logo.png"></a>Ranks</h1>    

<nav>
  
  <ul>
    
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <li><a class="active" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ranks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>

    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your logo inside the nav tag and write css for nav as: `display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;`

And also you have given so much unnecessary margin in nav li, so I removed it.

I have write an example for you. Check it out.

```css
h1 {
  font-size: 40px;  
  font-weight: 100px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: #d82d83;
}

nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
nav li {
    padding: 10px 5px;
    background-color: none;
    font-size: 16px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;    
}
nav ul li a{
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 7px 6px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <h1><a href="#"></a>Ranks</h1>   
  <ul>
    
    <div style="text-align: center;">
    <li><a class="active" href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ranks</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>

    </div>
  </ul>
</nav>
```